# getElementById between two cells google colaboratory

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have this cell:

## Cell 1

```
from IPython import display, HTML

display(HTML(
      '''
      <img src="value_to_replace" id="yeah">
      '''
    ))
```

And this

## Cell 2

```
%%javascript

const yeahElem = document.getElementById("yeah");


yeahElem.src = `data:image/png;base64,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`;
```

However, the cell 1 output didn't update the image. I was trying debugging in inspect element in console, it shows that the `yeahElem` variable is null:

```
Error evaluating Javascript output:  TypeError: yeahElem is null
```

Btw the image is supposed to be [image], I tried this manually the cell 2 in console of browser, I'm using firefox btw.

It works if I put all code in same cell (it doesn't communicate between two cells output):

```
%%html
<img src="value_to_replace" id="yeah">

<script>

const yeahElem = document.getElementById("yeah");
yeahElem.src = `data:image/png;base64,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`;

</script>
```

Comment: This could be to do with the render order, could you instead just put the `src` attribute value in place of `value_to_replace`? If you don't want to do that you should check that the javascript isn't running before the HTML has rendered

Comment: @Harrison I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean put the `src` attribute value in place of `value_to_replace`.

Comment: In `display(HTML(...`, replace: `src="value_to_replace"` with:  `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...."` instead of making JavaScript do it. (but use the whole line (there's not enough characters in the comment, unless I make a full answer)

Comment: @Harrison see my edited answer, is that what you mean? where I invoke html in same cell in whole line. Yeah it gave me output what I want. But I expect the the output / image is updated by another cell with running another cell which is javascript cell. (when cell 2 js is running, it's updating cell 1 output)